# HOCs, Context API and Next Pages

Tags: server-side-rendering, react-context, high-order-component

Its possible to use Hoc with context api inside a next page?

I have a next page generated by SSR, and a HOC privateRoute to validate authorization on this page. But for every access, we have a authorization request and its sound's me like a problem.

My idea is to use contexApi to get data one time, and reuse that on auth private route.

Anyone has a minimal exemple about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

The problem was to use Context inside react class component.

```js
mport React, { Component } from 'react'
import UserContext from './UserContext'

class HomePage extends Component {
  static contextType = UserContext

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = this.context

    console.log(user) // { name: 'Tania', loggedIn: true }
  }
for more, see https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/
  render() {
    return <div>{user.name}</div>
  }
}
```